# Is there a way to automatically register trait implementors?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to load JSON files that refer to structs implementing a trait. When the JSON files are loaded, the struct is grabbed from a hashmap. The problem is, I'll probably have to have a lot of structs put into that hashmap all over my code. I would like to have that done automatically. To me this seems to be doable with procedural macros, something like:

```
#[my_proc_macro(type=ImplementedType)]
struct MyStruct {}

impl ImplementedType for MyStruct {}

fn load_implementors() {
    let implementors = HashMap::new();
    load_implementors!(implementors, ImplementedType);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What does "registering trait implementors" mean here? Does it mean each time you call `impl X` it's somehow tracked somewhere? You might want a style more like `#[impl_track]` you can put before your `impl X for Y`, then use a macro to dig in and see what's implementing what to track it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that [Rust Analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io) already does this for raw source, so maybe you could just use that instead?

Comment: @tadman Yes that's exactly what I meant (sorry if I didn't make it clear), I'm looking for some macro to do that. I don't know how I'd use Rust Analyzer in a sane way.

Comment: @kmdreko Linkme seems perfect in this case, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### No

There is a core issue that makes it difficult to skip manually inserting into a structure. Consider this simplified example, where we simply want to print values that are provided separately in the code-base:

```
my_register!(alice);
my_register!(bob);

fn main() {
    my_print(); // prints "alice" and "bob"
}
```

In typical Rust, there is no mechanism to link the `my_print()` call to the multiple invocations of `my_register`. There is no support for declaration merging, run-time/compile-time reflection, or run-before-main execution that you might find in other languages that might make this possible (unless of course there's something I'm missing).

---

### But Also Yes

There are third party crates built around link-time tricks that can make this possible:

- [`ctor`](https://crates.io/crates/ctor) allows you to define functions that are executed before `main()`. With it, you can have `my_register!()` create invididual functions for `alice` and `bob` that when executed will add themselves to some global structure which can then be accessed by `my_print()`.
- [`linkme`](https://crates.io/crates/linkme) allows you to define a slice that is made from elements defined separately, which are combined at compile time. The `my_register!()` simply needs to use this crate's attributes to add an element to the slice, which `my_print()` can easily access.

I understand skepticism of these methods since the declarative approach is often clearer to me, but sometimes they are necessary or the ergonomic benefits outweigh the "magic".